# Use generated header file from Cython

Tags: c, cython

According to the [documentation](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#using-cython-declarations-from-c) it is possible to use C header files generated from Cython. I have followed the `Hello World` example with no problem and now I want to try something different. I want to use a public declaration to be able to use a custom method. My code structure is the following:

- hello.pyx
- setup.py
- main.c

**hello.pyx**

```
cdef public void say_hello():
    print("Hello World")
```

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [
    Extension("hello", ["hello.pyx", "main.c"]),
]

setup(
  name='Hello app',
  cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
  ext_modules=ext_modules
)
```

**main.c**

```
#include "hello.h"

int main(void){
    say_hello();
}
```

The `main.c` acts as a test file to verify that the `say_hello()` method works as intended.
Building the setup file `python3 setup.py build_ext` produces the following output.

```
    running build_ext
    skipping 'hello.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    building 'hello' extension
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.5m -c hello.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/hello.o
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.5m -c main.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/main.o
    In file included from main.c:1:0:
    hello.h:26:1: error: unknown type name ‘PyMODINIT_FUNC’
     PyMODINIT_FUNC inithello(void);
     ^
    error:

 command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

The hello.h file contains the following

```
    /* Generated by Cython 0.25.2 */

#ifndef __PYX_HAVE__hello
#define __PYX_HAVE__hello


#ifndef __PYX_HAVE_API__hello

#ifndef __PYX_EXTERN_C
  #ifdef __cplusplus
    #define __PYX_EXTERN_C extern "C"
  #else
    #define __PYX_EXTERN_C extern
  #endif
#endif

#ifndef DL_IMPORT
  #define DL_IMPORT(_T) _T
#endif

__PYX_EXTERN_C DL_IMPORT(void) say_hello(void);

#endif /* !__PYX_HAVE_API__hello */

#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION < 3
PyMODINIT_FUNC inithello(void);  // <-- Line 26
#else
PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_hello(void);
#endif

#endif /* !__PYX_HAVE__hello */
```

To my understanding, it seems that gcc in not able to get the right version of Python (I'm using Python 3.5). Is there a way to set that somehow? Also, if that is indeed the case, why isn't this *linking* taken care of when I run the `python3 setup.py build_ext` command?

I don't have much experience with C so I might be missing something.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the problem is your misconception, that `distutils` will build the executable for you. That is not the case.

Out goal is to use some python functionality from a C-program. Let's do the necessary steps by ourselves:

1. Using cython to produce `hello.h` and `hello.c` from the given pyx-file.
2. Using the created `hello.h` for importing the python functionality in a C-program (`main.c`).
3. Using a compiler to compile both files `hello.c` and `main.c`.
4. Using a linker to link the in the last step created object files to an executable.

The first step is easy:

```
#hello.pyx:
cdef public void say_hello():
    print("Hello World")


>>>python -m cython hello.pyx
```

Now we have `hello.c` and `hello.h` in our working directory. Your `main.c` is wrong and should look like the following:

```
//main.c
#include <Python.h> //needed
#include "hello.h"

int main(void){
    Py_Initialize();  //Needed!
    inithello();      //Needed! called PyInit_hello() for Python3
    say_hello();
    Py_Finalize();    //Needed!
}
```

**Important:** If you use Python>=3.5 and Cython>=0.29 you must take multi-phase module initialisation into account, as described in this [SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55669343/5769463) - otherwise the resulting program will crash.

I'm not sure why the result of the cython doesn't include `Python.h` (this would make it self-contained), but this is the way it is - you need to include it prior to `hello.h`. Also `Py_Initialize()` and `Py_Finalize()` should be called before and after the usage of the functionality from `hello.h`.Also you need to initialize the module `hello` with `inithello()` otherwise a segmentation fault will haunt you at the start of the executable.

Now we need to find the flags for compiling. This can be done with the utility `/usr/bin/python-config` (I use python2.7, you need to do the same for python3) and option `--cflags`:

```
>>> /usr/bin/python-config --cflags
-I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python2.7
-fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong
-Wformat -Werror=format-security  -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes
```

So let's build it:

```
>>>gcc -c hello.c -o hello.o <our cflags>
>>>gcc -c main.c -o main.o <our cflags>
```

Now we have both object files `hello.o` and `main.o` in our working directory. We need to link them and in order to find the right flags we use once again the `python-config` utility but this time with the `--ldflags`-option:

```
>>> /usr/bin/python-config --ldflags
--L/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib -lpython2.7 
-lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm  -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions
```

That means:

```
>>> gcc main.o hello.o -o prog <our ldflags>
```

And now we have finally our executable!

---

Actually, it is not exactly what is asked for, but there is another possibility to generate an executable from the cython code, by using the option `--embed`. With this switch on not only the module is cythonized but also a main-function is created. For this your `hello.pyx` could look as follows:

```
#hello.pyx:
cdef public void say_hello():
    print("Hello World")
##main:
say_hello()
```

It is possible also to use `__name__=="__main__"` trick, but not needed.

Now after running:

```
>>>python -m cython hello.pyx --embed
```

a `main` function is created in the resulting `hello.c` which takes care of setting up/initializing the python-environment. So we just can build and link it:

```
>>> gcc hello.c -o prog <our cflags> <our ldflags>
```

And we are done - no need to know, how to initialize the whole python-stuff right!

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ead, the tip on finding the flags was very useful.

Alas, during the compilation of `main.c` I get an implicit declaration warning for method `inithello()`  which later throws an error `undefined reference to inithello`when I'm attempting linking. 

Using Python2.7 works fine!

Comment: @BitWhyz By looking into the hello.h code, I think you should use `PyInit_hello()` instead of `inithello()` in Python3.

Comment: It worked! Thank you. I don't understand why the documentation does not mention that. I would appreciate a good resource for digging in more.

Comment: @BitWhyz it is pretty hard to write good documentation, even harder than to write good code. I think the guys from cython are doing a decent job, but a lot is changing from version to version and this is not simple to keep track.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `api` keyword

```
cdef api void hello():
    print("hello")
    return;
```

This  will autogenerate a "hello.h" when compiling.