# Calling Cython function from C code raises segmentation fault

Tags: c, python-3.x, cython

I'm trying to call cython (cdef) function in C program. When the cdef function contains python statements, e.g. print(0.5), or python (def) functions, calling the (cdef) function raises a segmentation fault.

The .pyx file:

```py
# cython: language_level=3

cdef public double PI = 3.1415926

cdef public double get_e():
    print("calling get_e()")
    return 2.718281828
```

The .c file:

```c
#include "Python.h"
#include "transcendentals.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  Py_Initialize();
  PyInit_transcendentals();
  printf("pi**e: %f\n", pow(PI, get_e()));
  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

The compiling commands:

```sh
cython transcendentals.pyx

gcc -I. -I/usr/include/python3.5m -I/usr/include/python3.5m \
-Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare \
-g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat \
-Werror=format-security -DNDEBUG -g \
-fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes \
-L/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu \
-L/usr/lib transcendentals.c main.c \
-lpython3.5m -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker \
-export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions
```

When I remove the print statement of get_e function, no segmentation fault would be raised. But the value of PI will be 0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you are using Cython 0.29. [Since 0.29](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/changes.html#id15), [PEP-489](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0489/) multi-phase module initialisation has been enabled for Python versions >=3.5. This means, using `PyInit_XXX` is no longer sufficient, as you are experiencing.

[Cython's documentation](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#public-declarations) suggest to use [inittab mechanism](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/import.html#c._inittab), i.e. your `main`-function should look something like:

```
#include "Python.h"
#include "transcendentals.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int status=PyImport_AppendInittab("transcendentals", PyInit_transcendentals);
  if(status==-1){
    return -1;//error
  } 
  Py_Initialize();
  PyObject *module = PyImport_ImportModule("transcendentals");

  if(module==NULL){
     Py_Finalize();
     return -1;//error
  }
  
  printf("pi**e: %f\n", pow(PI, get_e()));
  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

Another possibility  to restore the old behavior would be to define macro `CYTHON_PEP489_MULTI_PHASE_INIT=0` and thus overriding the default by e.g. passing `-DCYTHON_PEP489_MULTI_PHASE_INIT=0` to gcc on the command line while compiling.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a bug (or at least an issue with **Python3.7**).

I tested your example on my Arch Linux with Python3.7.

First thing which made me curious was how long the compilation took on this step:

```
gcc -I. -I/usr/include/python3.7m -I/usr/include/python3.7m -Wno-unused-result \
-Wsign-compare -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g \
-fwrapv -O0 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -L/usr/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-x86_64-linux-gnu \
-L/usr/lib transcendentals.c main.c -lpython3.7m -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm
```

I have a not so bad computer but it took it a couple of minutes to get this compilation done. Strange.

And upon running `./a.out`, I also got a segmentation error, like you.

---

So, then I decided to test (with one minor modification: change `PyInit_transcendentals` to `inittranscendentals` in `main`) with Python2.7, as shown below:

```
gcc -I. -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -Wno-unused-result \
-Wsign-compare -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security \
-g -fwrapv -O0 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config-2.7-x86_64-linux-gnu \
-L/usr/lib transcendentals.c main.c -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm
```

The compilation was instant.

I ran `./a.out` and the output was:

> called get_e():2.718282calling get_e() 
>   pi**e: 22.459157

---

Then just to be sure, that this had nothing to do with any flags that you might be using, nor that the math library nor something else would be having an effect here, I repeated the test with a very simple "hello world" example as shown below.

- main.c

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "hello.h"

int main() {
  Py_Initialize();
  inithello();
  hello();
  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

- hello.c

```
# cython: language_level=2

cdef public hello():
    print "hello!"
```

Then,

```
cython hello.pyx
cc -c *.c -I /usr/include/python2.7/
cc -L /usr/lib/python2.7/ -lpython2.7 -ldl *.o -o main
./main
```

The output was,

> hello!

On the other hand, recompling with Python3.7 (after changing `inithello` to `PyInit_hello`) gave the following output:

```
cc -c *.c -I /usr/include/python3.7m/
cc -L /usr/lib/python3.7/ -lpython3.7m -ldl *.o -o main
./main
```

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Thank you! I also tested on python2.7, and it works.

Comment: It seems to be a bug of python 3.

Comment: OR .. `:)` we both don't know how to correctly configure Python3 for this. Maybe they changed something in Python3 from Python2. But then again, I am not aware of what else to configure. Better put up a bug report on the relevant python forum.

Anyways, all the more reason to keep Python 2 as well as Python 3 on my PC. `:D`

Comment: I created an issue about this on github. An contributor replied me this. "Calling the module init function (and throwing away the module reference that it returns) is not the right thing to do in Python 3. Leave that to CPython. You can use the inittab mechanism to integrate with a statically linked extension module."

Comment: oh! `:O` cool! I learned something new today. Thanks for sharing that @XiaojianLuo. If that works, then you can post that correct Python3 code as your own answer to this question.

Comment: yes cool ! I am always happy to learn something. I upvoted the correct answer. `:)`