# Rightly compiled code(without error) giving Segmentation fault core dumped

Tags: python, c++, cython

I am using cython to use python functions in c++, which itself calls a c++ function, Everything compiled perfectly well, but in the end step the error occurs: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` when running the out file, I know its a tough ask to find the mistake but can someone please help me:

```
#include  <iostream>
#include  "Python.h"
#include  "./plugins/strat_plugin.h" //cython generated header file
int main(int argc, char  *argv[])
{
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys\n" "import os"); 
PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append( os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()) +'/plugins/')");
int status=PyImport_AppendInittab("start_plugin", &initstrat_plugin);
if(status==-1){
    std::cout<<"error in appendinit"<<"\n";
    return -1;//error
} 
Py_Initialize();
PyObject *module = PyImport_ImportModule("strat_plugin");
if(module==NULL){
    PyErr_Print();
    Py_Finalize();
    std::cout<<"error in import"<<"\n";
    return -1;//error
}
    long long ans=0;
    std::list<int> a;
    ans=gen_fibonacci(a,1,100); //this is the cython function
    std::cout<<"ans: "<<ans;
    std::cout<<"\n";
}
```

compile:

```
g++-8 ./plugins/strat_plugin.c helper.cpp $(python-config --libs)  $(python-config --includes)  $(python-config --cflags)
```

strat_plugin.pyx file:

```
from libcpp.list cimport list
from test import test_sum

cdef public long long gen_fibonacci(list[int] &l,int ind,int  n):
    num = 3
    t1 = 0 
    t2 = 1
    nextTerm = 0
    i=1
    if ind==1:
        l.push_back(0)
        l.push_back(1)
        i=3
    if ind==2:
        l.push_back(1)
        i=2
    while i<n:
        nextTerm=t1+t2
        t1=t2
        t2=nextTerm
        if num>=ind:
            i=i+1
            l.push_back(nextTerm)
        num=num+1
    return test_sum(l)
```

This compiles well with the command: `cython -2 strat_plugin.pyx` producing header and the c file.

strat.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <list>
long long sum(std::list<int> &);
```

strategy.cpp

## include "strat.h"

using namespace std;

```
long long sum(list<int> &l)
{
    long long s =0;
    for(list<int>::const_iterator i = l.begin(); i != l.end(); i++)
    s+= *i ;
    return s;
}
```

strat.pyx:

```
from libcpp.list cimport list

cdef extern from "strat.h":
    long long sum(list[int] &)

def test_sum(list[int] l):
    return sum(l)
```

setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [Extension("test", ["strat.pyx", "strategy.cpp"], language='c++',)]

setup(cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext}, ext_modules = ext_modules)
```

compile using:

```
python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

**more relevant information:**
I tried debugging it with gdb and get this:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7a2569b in PyImport_GetModuleDict () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0
```

I don't really get the error can someone point out what's wrong?

Comment: Why does this have to do with c?

Comment: "Rightly compiled code" -- All that means is that there are no syntax errors.  It has nothing to do with how your code will behave at runtime, whether it has logical errors or not.

Comment: There's no way to replicate this without `test_sum`.

Comment: Also, you should see if there is an issue with `test_sum` by commenting it out and returning `1` or some other value.  If there is no segmentation fault, then `test_sum` is more than likely the issue.  In general, you should debug this by divide and conquer, to see what finally works when code is removed.

Comment: As the duplicate says: from Python3.5 onwards use `PyImport_AppendInittab` rather than calling `PyInit_*` directly. [The documentation has recently been updated to give a clearer example](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/embedding.html)

Comment: I tried that too, see the updated code now, it does not show any error till importing, it just gives segmentation fault

Comment: I've reopened the question because it looks like [the proposed duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55647555/calling-cython-function-from-c-code-raises-segmentation-fault?noredirect=1&lq=1) doesn't solve all your problems.

Answer (score 1):

Removing `test_sum` (since I don't have the code to it), ignoring the overflow error (your python code exceeds the range of an int in the `while` loop), and changing `PyInit_strat_plugin` to `initstrat_plugin`, it works fine for me.

Comment: `PyInit_strat_plugin` -> `initstrat_plugin` is difference between Python 2 and 3. Obviously given OP doesn't say which they were using it's anyone's guess...

Comment: @David Schwartz I have tested test_sum, it is not causing any issues, actually it is a c++ function, compiles to so file using python, I have tested it in shell and it works perfectly fine

Comment: If it's not causing issues then it should not be part of an [mre]; It's a distraction we have to wade through

Comment: @David I looked at your answer and tried to return 0 instead of test_sum(l), but the error still is there.... can you tell me how exactly you ignored test_sum?

Comment: @DeepanshNagaria That's how I did it. I made it return a constant and I removed the `import` statement. But you need to ask a new question. If you could replicate the error without `test_sum`, why did you include it in your question in the first place? You need to ask about *ONLY* what's causing your problem or we have no idea what to look at. Keep removing things until you either have *very* simple code containing only what's causing the problem or you identify the one specific thing causing the problem and remove everything else.