# How Cython convert python code with some python libraries like scipy into C++ correctly?

Tags: python, c++, dll, scipy, cython

0 My aim is to embedding some python code with scipy library into C++ code, and I want to run the C++ code without any python installation. This is my current process:

1
Saving the following code as a .pyx file:

```
import scipy.stats as sp
cdef public float ppf(const float c, const float a, const float s):
    return sp.gamma.ppf(c, a=a, loc=0, scale=s)
```

2 Using "cython" to generate .c and .h file

```
cython XXX.pyx
```

3 Generating .dll file from .c and .h with Visual Studio:

```
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) float __stdcall _ppf(const float c, const float r, const float k)
    {
        return ppf(c, r, k);
    }
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (fdwReason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        Py_Initialize();
        PyInit_ppf();
        break;
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        Py_Finalize();
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

4 Calling the .dll file without python installation:

```
int main()
{
    typedef int(*pAdd)(const float c, const float r, const float k);
    HINSTANCE hDLL = LoadLibrary(_T("Win32Project.dll"));
    if (hDLL)
    {
        pAdd pFun = (pAdd)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "_ppf");
        if (pFun)
        {
            float i = pFun(0.0000001, 5.0, 1.0);
            cout << "i = " << i << endl;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

5 The code outputs a very large random value(however the correct result is fixed around 1.0). I also test a simple addition operation in step 1 without scipy dependency to verify correctness of the pipeline, and it works. But I don't know what is wrong when I use scipy library. How can I convert the python with scipy into dll correctly?

Note: I guess there should be many dependencies with scipy, so I use "pyinstaller" to generate all relative .dll files. I put these files into the Visual Studio project directory at the same level as *.exe, it still doesn't work. I don't know whether I use these files correctly, or any other reason?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling Cython function from C code raises segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55647555/calling-cython-function-from-c-code-raises-segmentation-fault)

Comment: In your case there is no segfault, but that is UB thus for different compilers the behavior can be different. You also should always check whether a command was successfully (PyInit_xxx).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The link doesn't contain any python dependency. It also can work in my pipeline, but when I add the scipy dependency in my pyx, it doesn't work,it bothers me so much...

Comment: Right - but if you _check the return value_ when you call `PyInit_` then you'd know if it failed. You could then call `PyErr_Print()` to see why. While you're skipping these basic debugging steps it's going to be pure guesswork as to what's going wrong