# Cython: Segmentation fault when using Python stuff in struct method

Tags: python, memory-management, segmentation-fault, runtime-error, cython

I have these files to reproduce the problem, mod2.pxd:

```
cdef public api:
    void myapi()

cdef public:
    cppclass myclass:
        void mymethod()
```

mod2.pyx

```
cdef void myapi():
    print("I am OK (from myapi)")

cdef cppclass myclass:
    void mymethod():
        # Using anything C is OK
        cdef int i = 0
        i += 1

        # Crash with Python var
        # Segmentation fault
        j = 0
        j += 1

        # Crash with Python function
        # Segmentation fault
        print("I am crashing!")
```

mod1.pxd

```
cdef public api:
    void myfunc()
```

mod1.pyx

```
from mod2 cimport myapi, myclass

cdef public cppclass foo:
    void bar():
        print("I am OK (from foo.bar)")

cdef void myfunc():
    print("I am OK")
    myapi()
    cdef foo f
    f.bar()

    # Stack var: Segmentation fault
    print("Calling myclass.mymethod...")
    cdef myclass t
    t.mymethod()

    # # Pointer: Segmentation fault
    # print("Calling myclass.mymethod...")
    # cdef myclass* t2 = new myclass()
    # t2.mymethod()

cpdef test():
    myfunc()
```

Main Python programme app.py

```
import mod1
mod1.test()
```

Result

```
I am OK
I am OK (from myapi)
I am OK (from foo.bar)
Calling myclass.mymethod...
Segmentation fault
```

It's a segmentation fault which happens in a Cython struct `myclass` when using anything Python. Also in mod2, but the global function `myapi` is OK. From a struct method `foo.bar` but in the same file is also OK.

I'm using Python 3.8.2, and Cython 0.29.26

mod1 and mod2 are translated into C++ with `cython -3 --cplus` command, and compiled with `gcc` to .so files. It happens the same when using Python build tool.

As suggested from https://stackoverflow.com/a/55669343/5581893
I tried to add `-DCYTHON_PEP489_MULTI_PHASE_INIT=0` to all `gcc` commands but no help.

This situation seems strange, why are Python stuff not touch-able from mod2 (fails in struct only)?