# import c-shared library that generated by cython to go with cgo

Tags: go, gcc, shared-libraries, cython, cgo

I wanna import a c-shared-library to go that generated by Cython in python 3.7, try do it by cgo.

in this case:

> go version go1.12.7 linux/amd64
>
> Python 3.7.3
>
> Cython version 0.29.12
>
> os: Manjaro 18.0.4
>
> Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.1.19-1

I will continue:
make a python file `vim pylib.pyx`:

```
#!python
cdef public void hello():
     print("hello world!")
```

and run `python -m cython pylib.pyx` for generate the c-shared-library, I have two files, `pylib.c` and `pylib.h`.
now, try import these to golang, so make a go file `vim test.go`:

```
package main

/*
#include </usr/include/python3.7m/Python.h>
#include "pylib.h"
*/
import "C"
import "fmt"

func main() {
   C.hello()
   fmt.Println("done")
}
```

finaly, I run `go run test.go`:
I have the following output:

> ```
> # command-line-arguments
> /usr/bin/ld: $WORK/b001/_x002.o: in function `_cgo_51159acd5c8e_Cfunc_hello':
> /tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:48: undefined reference to `hello'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> ```

I try import it to c too but I encountered a similar output like this:

> ```
> undefined reference to `hello'
> ld returned 1 exit status
> ```

I don't know what to do, help me, please. 
:(

Comment: The cgo docs only show this working with single line comments `//`, have you tried that?

Comment: That question is way too broad. Let’s start with the fact that cythonized files .c/.h aren’t shared objects. Then you need too embed the python interpreter - the list goes on and on...

Comment: @Jesse thanks for feedback <3. Do you mean?

     ...
    //#include </usr/include/python3.7m/Python.h>
    //#include "pylib.h"
    import "C"
    ...

so I have same problem too.

Comment: I think you should read - in detail - the section of the Cython documentation describing how to call a Cython module from C and then reproduce that in Go as closely as possible.

Comment: @ead first I tried import go lib to python, It done with ctypes in python and I wanted to do the opposite, And I read documents from various sites that said I should do it.
I got help from these:

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45419532/use-generated-header-file-from-cython)
and any more that I can't finde them.

I thought be import to go like import to c. 
I had a similar output, of course.

Comment: @davidw I couldn't find anything to helpful, Can you find it to help me?or something.

Comment: [This is the relevant section](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#using-cython-declarations-from-c); it follows the same pattern as ead's answer from the question you link above and for example the "main" function includes a number of things that you ignore here.

Comment: @DavidW so thanks, I have to study it now. <3

Comment: @hamidghadery as you work with Python3.7 please take my last edit into consideration: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45424720/revisions

Comment: @hamidghadery Btw, don't mind the downvotes - the question isn't bad - it is just too broad : it would take hours to answer it propertly. I think you will be able to handle it with links provided by DavidW - and then you can write an answer yourself. If not, you can come back with a more specific question.

Comment: @ead I don't actually think it is that broad - I'd guess that someone familiar with (C)Go could translate the working C examples in the documentation really quite quickly. That person definitely isn't me. (My problem with this question is that it doesn't seem to have started from those examples so there's a lot wrong, but hopefully OP can fix that...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I run go run test.go: I have the following output:
>
> ```
> # command-line-arguments
> /usr/bin/ld: $WORK/b001/_x002.o: in function `_cgo_51159acd5c8e_Cfunc_hello':
> /tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:48: undefined reference to `hello'
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> ```

---

We can generate an equivalent error message with the following code.

```
package main

/*
#include <math.h>
*/
import "C"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    cube2 := C.pow(2.0, 3.0)
    fmt.Println(cube2)
}
```

Output:

```
$ go run cube2.go
# command-line-arguments
/usr/bin/ld: $WORK/b001/_x002.o: in function `_cgo_f6c6fa139eda_Cfunc_pow':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:53: undefined reference to `pow'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
$
```

In both cases, `ld` (the linker) can't find a C function after looking in the usual places: `undefined reference to 'pow'` or `undefined reference to 'hello'`.

Let's tell `cgo` where to find the C `pow` function in the C `math` library: `m`.

For `cgo`, using `ld` flags,

```
#cgo LDFLAGS: -lm
```

[GCC: 3.14 Options for Linking](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html)

> ```
> -llibrary
>     Search the library named library when linking.
> ```

Updating the previous code,

```
package main

/*
#cgo LDFLAGS: -lm
#include <math.h>
*/
import "C"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    cube2 := C.pow(2.0, 3.0)
    fmt.Println(cube2)
}
```

Output:

```
$ go run cube2.go
8
$
```

---

This illustrates a basic `cgo` principle: include a C header file for your C library and point to the location of the C library.

---

References:

[Cgo and Python](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/engineering/cgo-and-python/) : [Embedding CPython: a primer](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/engineering/cgo-and-python/#embedding-cpython-a-primer)

Comment: Actually, because the Python interpreter must be embeded there is a little bit more to it. We need a "translation" to go of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45419532/use-generated-header-file-from-cython or https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#using-cython-declarations-from-c