# ImportError after cython embed

Tags: python, module, cython

I can't get otherwise-available modules seen by a compiled python script. How do I need to change the below process in order to accept either venv-based or global modules?

Steps:

```sh
$ python3 -m venv sometest
$ cd sometest
$ . bin/activate
(sometest) $ pip3 install PyCrypto Cython
```

The basic script, using a non-standard module `Crypto`:

```py
# hello.py
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64
obj = AES.new('This is a key123', AES.MODE_CBC, 'This is an IV456')
msg = "The answer is no"
ciphertext = obj.encrypt(msg)
print(msg)
print(base64.b64encode(ciphertext))
```

```sh
(sometest) $ python3 hello.py
The answer is no
b'1oONZCFWVJKqYEEF4JuL8Q=='
```

Compiling it:

```sh
(sometest) $ cython -3 --embed hello.py
(sometest) $ gcc -Os -I /usr/include/python3.5m -o hello hello.c -lpython3.5m -lpthread -lm -lutil -ldl
(sometest) $ $ ./hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 1, in init hello
    from Crypto.Cipher import AES
ImportError: No module named 'Crypto'
```

I don't think it's a problem with using the venv from a cython-embedded-compiled script: the script works elsewhere in the system without the venv (that is, `python3 -c 'from Crypto.Cipher import AES'` does not fail).

The process works fine otherwise:

```sh
(sometest) $ echo 'print("hello world")' > hello2.py
(sometest) $ cython -3 --embed hello2.py
(sometest) $ gcc -Os -I /usr/include/python3.5m -o hello2 hello2.c -lpython3.5m -lpthread -lm -lutil -ldl
(sometest) $ ./hello2
hello world
```

System:

```sh
(sometest) $ python3 --version
Python 3.5.2
(sometest) $ pip3 freeze
Cython==0.29.11
pkg-resources==0.0.0
pycrypto==2.6.1

(sometest) $ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS"
```

Comment: The embedded python has probably not the same pythonpath

Comment: That's it, thank you @ead. I had *assumed* that it would use the same source of modules that otherwise work. Now, I see that `PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ ./hello` works. While I feel a little embarrassed it was that simple, I feel it's worth enough to not delete this. If you answer, I'll accept. Thank you again!

Comment: I hope it is clear to you, that ith your solution the embeded iterpreter uses system-installation and not from the virtual environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, a Python-interpreter isn't "standalone" and in order to work it needs its standard libraries (for example `ctypes` (compiled) or `site.py` (interpreted)) and also path to other site-packages (for example `numpy`) must be set.

Albeit it is possible to make a Python-interpter fully standalone by freezing the py-modules and merging all c-extensions (see for example [this SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52959902/5769463)) into the resulting executable, it is easier to provide the needed installation to the embeded interpeter. One can download files needed for a "standard" installation from python-homepage (at least for [windows](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/)), see also this [SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62390978/5769463)).

Sometimes finding standard modules/site packages doesn't work out of the box: one has to help the interpreter by setting Python-path, i.e. by adding `<..>/sometest/lib/python3.5/site-packages` (`sometest` being a virtual environment root-folder) to `sys.path` either programmatically in the pyx-file or by setting `PYTHONPATH`-environment variable prior to start.

Read on for more gory details and alternative solutions.

---

This answer is for Linux and Python3 (Python 3.7), the basic idea is the same for Windows/MacOS, but some details might be different.

Because `venv` is used we have the following alternative to solve the issue:

- adding `<..>/sometest/lib/python3.5/site-packages` (`sometest` being a virtual environment root-folder) to `sys.path` either programmatically in the pyx-file or by setting `PYTHONPATH`-environment variable prior to start.
- placing the executable with embeded python in a subdirectory of `sometest` (e.g. `bin` or creating an own).
- using `virtualenv` instead of `venv`.

Note: For the executable with the embeded python, it doesn't play any role whether the virtual environment (or which) is activated or not.

---

Why does the above solves the issue in your scenario?

The problem is, that the (embeded) Python-interpreter needs to figure out where following things are:

- platform independent directory/files, e.g. `os.py`, `argparse.py` (mostly everything *.py/ *.pyc). Given [`sys.prefix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.prefix), the interpreter can figure out where to find them (i.e. in `prefix/lib/pythonX.Y`).
- platform dependent directory/files, e.g. shared libraries. Given [`sys.exec_prefix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exec_prefix) the interpreter can figure out where to find them (e.g. shared libraries can be found in  in `exec_prefix/lib/pythonX.Y/lib-dynload`).

The algorithm can be [found here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Modules/getpath.c#L14) and the search is performed, when [`Py_Initialize`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#c.Py_Initialize) is executed. Once these directories are found, `sys.path` can be constructed.

However, when using `venv`, there is a `pyvenv.cfg`-file [next to exe or in the parent directory](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Modules/getpath.c#L736), which ensures that the right Python-Home is found - a good starting point is the `home`-key in this file.

If [`Py_NoSiteFlag`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#c.Py_NoSiteFlag) is not set, `Py_Initialize` will utilize [`site.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9048c49322a5229ff99610aba35913ffa295ebb7/Lib/site.py#L16) (it can be found by the interpreter, because `sys.prefix` is known) , or more precise [`site.main()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9048c49322a5229ff99610aba35913ffa295ebb7/Lib/site.py#L548), to add site-packages of the virtual environment to `sys.path`. While doing so, `site.py` looks for `pyvenv.cfg` and parses it. However, local `site-packages` are added to the python-path only when:

> If a file named "pyvenv.cfg" exists one directory above
>   sys.executable, sys.prefix and sys.exec_prefix are set to that
>   directory and it is also checked for site-packages (sys.base_prefix
>   and sys.base_exec_prefix will always be the "real" prefixes of the
>   Python installation).

In your case `pyvenv.cfg` is not in the directory above, but in the same as the exe - thus the local site-packages, where the libraries were installed via pip, aren't included. Global site-packages  aren't included because `pyvenv.cfg` has key `include-system-site-packages = false`. Thus there are no site-packages allowed and the installed libraries cannot be found.

However, moving the exe one directory down, would lead to inclusion of the local site-packages to the path.

---

There are other scenarios possible, what counts is the location of the executable and not which environment is activated.

**A: Executable is somewhere, but not inside a virtual environment**

This search heuristic works more or less reliable for installed python-interpreters, but can fall for embeded-interpreters or virtual environments (see [this issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue22213) for much more information).

If python was installed using usual `apt install` or similar, then it will be found (due to [4. step](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Modules/getpath.c#L74) in the search algorithm) and the system-installation will be used by the embeded interpreter.

However if files were moved around or python was build from source but not installed, then embeded interperter cannot start up:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

In this case, [`Py_SetPythonHome`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/init.html#c.Py_SetPythonHome) or setting environment variable `$PYTHONHOME` are possible solutions.

**B: Executable inside a  virtual environment, created with virtualenv**

Assuming it is the same Python version  for virtual environment and the embeded python (otherwise we have the above case), the emebeded exe will use local side-packages. The home search algorithmus will always find the local home, due to [this rule](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Modules/getpath.c#L68):

> Step 3. Try to find prefix and exec_prefix relative to argv0_path, backtracking up the path until it is exhausted.  This is the most common  step to succeed.  Note that if prefix and exec_prefix are
>   different,  exec_prefix is more likely to be found; however if
>   exec_prefix is a  subdirectory of prefix, both will be found.

In this case  `argv0_path` is the path to the exe (there is no `pyvenv.cfg` file!), and the ["landmarks"](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Modules/getpath.c#L54) (lib/python$VERSION/os.py and lib/python$VERSION/lib-dynload) will be found, because they are presented as symlinks in the local-home above the exe.

**C: Executable two folders deep inside a `venv`-environment**

Going two and not one folder (where it works) down in a `venv`-environment results in case A: `pyvenv.cfg` file isn't read while searching for home (too far above), 'venv`-environments lack symlinks to "landmarkers" (localy only side-packages are present) and such step 3 will fail, with [4. step](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Modules/getpath.c#L74) being the only hope.

---

**Corollary:** Embeded Python will not work without a right Python-installation, unless among other possibilities:

- the needed files are packed into `lib\pythonX.Y\*` next to the embeding executable or somewhere above (and there is no `pyvenv.cfg` around to mess the search up).
- or `pyvenv.cfg` used to point the interpreter to the right location.

Comment: This is a lot to take in. I did not know there was a (significant) difference between `venv` and `virtualenv`. When I try the steps *outside* of either (assuming modules available globally, no `PYTHONPATH` set), it works without error; this helps me to understand a few things. Your answer will take a few for me to take in, thank you for taking the time for a thorough answer!

Comment: I understand that the embedded executable still needs a "complete" python installation, but when I run `./hello` it fails despite having `lib/python3.5/site-packages/Crypto` next to the executable. Is it a safer interpretation of *"next to the embeding executable"* to assume that the executable must be in a subdir next to `./lib/`? (I hadn't realized that nuance of venv's, but now I see the behavior difference.)

Comment: @r2evans If there are no `pyvenv.cfg` around to mess the search up, then "next to exe" is enough (at least for Python3.7 - cannot test it with Python3.5), but your proposal is safer (putting exe in a subfolder), because it also works when `pyenv.cfg` is around.