# Prevent a Python-embedded to look in my default path C:\Python38 for modules

Tags: python, path, environment-variables, cython, python-embedding

I'm using Cython in `--embed` mode to produce a .exe. I'm evaluating the [Minimal set of files required to distribute an embed-Cython-compiled code and make it work on any machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62390978/minimal-set-of-files-required-to-distribute-an-embed-cython-compiled-code-and-ma/62392087#62392087). To do this, I only copy a minimal number of files from the Python Windows [embeddable package](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/).

In order to check this, I need to be sure that the current process I'm testing *doesn't* in fact use my system default Python install, i.e. C:\Python38.

To do this, I open a new `cmd.exe` and do `set PATH=` which temporarily removes everything from the PATH. Then I can test any self-compiled `app.exe` and make sure it doesn't reuse `C:\Python38`'s files under the hood.

It works, except for the modules. Even after doing `set PATH=`, my code `app.py`

```
import json
print(json.dumps({"a":"b"}))
```

when Cython-`--embed`-compiled into a .exe works, but it still uses `C:\Python38\Lib\json\__init__.py`! I know this for sure, because if I temporarily remove this file, my .exe now fails, because it cannot find the `json` module.

**How to completely remove any link to `C:\Python38` when debugging a Python program which shouldn't use these files?**

Why isn't `set PATH=` enough? Which other environment variable does it use for modules? I checked all my system variables and I think I don't find any which seems related to Python.

Comment: `PATH` has to do with where Windows looks for exes. It has *nothing* to do with where Python looks for modules

Comment: @DavidW Ok, but why does an embedded version of python (installed somewhere else) look for modules in my `C:\Python38` folder? Is there a Windows registry key that informs about this, or another environment variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ead's answer and his link [`getpath.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Modules/getpath.c#L97) finally redirecting to [`getpathp.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/PC/getpathp.c#L18) in the case of Windows, we can learn that the rule for building the path for module etc. is:

- current directory first
- `PYTHONPATH` env. variable
- registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python` or the same in `HKCU`
- `PYTHONHOME` env. variable
- finally:

  > Iff - we can not locate the Python Home, have not had a PYTHONPATH
  > specified, and can't locate any Registry entries (ie, we have *nothing*
  > we can assume is a good path), a default path with relative entries is
  > used (eg. .\Lib;.\DLLs, etc)

---

**Conclusion**: in order to debug an embedded version of Python, without interfering with the default system install (C:\Python38 in my case), I finally solved it by temporarily renaming the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python` to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PythonOld`.

Side note: I'm not sure I will ever revert this registry key back to normal: my normal Python install shouldn't need it anyway to find its path, since when I run `python.exe` from anywhere (it is in the `PATH` for everyday use), it will automatically look in `.\Lib\` and `.\DLL\` which is correct. I don't see a single use case in which my normal install `python.exe` wouldn't find its subdir `.\Lib\` or `.\DLL\` and requiring the registry for this. In which use case would the registry be necessary? if `python.exe` is started then its path has been found, and it can take its `.\Lib` subfolder, without help from registry. I think 99,99% of the time this registry feature is doing more harm than good, preventing a Python install to be really "portable" (i.e. that we can move from one folder to another).

---

Notes:

- To be 100% sure, I also did this in command line, but I don't think it's necessary:

  ```
  set PATH=
  set PYTHONPATH=
  set PYTHONHOME=
  ```
- Might be helpful to do debugging of an embedded Python: `import ctypes`. If you haven't `_ctypes.pyd` and `libffi-7.dll` in your embedded install folder, it *should* fail. If it doesn't, this means it looks somewhere else (probably in your default system-wide Python install).

Answer (score 1):

Python has a quite complicated heuristic for finding its "installation" (see for example this [SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56857449/5769463) or this [description](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Modules/getpath.c#L14)), so probably it doesn't find the installation you are providing but the "default" installation.

Probably the most simple way is to set the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` pointing to the desired installation prior to start of the embedded interpreter.

By examination of `sys.path` one can check whether the correct installation was found.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried `set PATH=` and `set PYTHONPATH=` in `cmd.exe` before running the Cython-`--embed`-executable in the same terminal, but this exe still looks in `C:\Python38`...  Indeed in this exe, I added `print(sys.path)` and it reveals `C:\python38` is still in it. Why? How to disable this?

Comment: @Basj this is really hard to tell, without knowing everything about your system, as the algorithm for finding the installation is quite complicated. For example we don't know what can be found inside your installation: if "landmark" site.py isn't there the algorithm will not get the desired output. Sadly, we could only guess what could go wrong.

Comment: Solved thanks to your help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73064910/1422096), thanks again @ead!